# CSS & Overriding Styles on Nested Elements works only partially

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am wondering about the following code:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Test HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
        </head>
<body>
<table class=foo cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
         <tr>
             <td><b>Contingency Table:</b></td>
             <td><table class=bar border="2" align="left">
                  <tr><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td><td>blaa</td></tr>
               </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

with the following CSS:

```
table {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        }  

table.bar {
        border-color: red;
        background-color: white;
}

table.bar td {
        background-color: green;
}

table.bar tr {
        background-color: black;
}

table.foo {
        border-color: blue;
        background-color: white;
}

table.foo td {
        border-color: black;
        background-color: yellow;
}

table.foo tr {
        background-color: yellow;
}
```

The problem is, when interchanging the classes "foo" and "bar" in the table and its nested table, the style of the td-tags is not correctly set, or at least as not as expected by me. When changing from outer "bar" and inner "foo" to outer "foo" and inner "bar" the colors change as expected, except for the colors of the td-element. What am I doing wrong here, since the other elements of a table change correctly?

I know that using `table table.foo {...}` would work, but this requires to know which style should be used for the inner/nested table and I don't really like this idea. I want to be able to interchange the styles when desired and not include the "inheritance" in the style-sheet... Also dictating the order of the foo or bar styles in the style-sheet is not desirable for me. Please correct me, if this is actually common HTML/CSS practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS - *Cascading* style sheets!

Put simply, if you switch the foo and bar classes in you tables, you'll also need to move the `table.foo` css rules above the `table.bar` classes.

**Explanation** If `bar` is nested in `foo` the css rule `table.foo td` matches both the tds in both the `foo` and `bar` tables. So it the `table.foo td` is declared after the `table.bar td` rule, the `table.foo td` rule overwrites the `table.bar td`

Comment: Thank you. But why then do the table and tr work, but not the td?

Comment: I don't think it is. In actual fact it appears that the color of the tr rule and td rules are the same. So in actual fact what you are seeing is the the td rule. I don't think setting `background-color` on tr actually works, atleast not across all major browsers.

Comment: Good point... Is there any way to achieve my goals (independent behavior) despite the _cascading_?

Comment: Not to sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to simply define table-styles that are interchangeable, although it seems actually not possible due to the _cascading_...

Comment: The only way would be to use the `>` operator `table.foo > tr > td` and `table.bar > tr > td`. Those rule will then only apply to td which are direct children of tr which are direct children of table.foo or table.bar. Although I don't recommend this, it's messy and goes and against the grain of css.

Comment: I tested it again, and for me at least, the table.bar {} and table.foo{} definitions are interchangeable. So are they different from table.bar td{} or table.bar tr{}? After all, I would assume that a nested table.bar would again collide with the superior table.foo...

Comment: because `table.foo` and `table.foo` relate exactly to those elements. Not their children. So `table.foo` doesn't match `table.bar`.

Answer (score 2):

xzyfer's reasoning is right. A simple workaround could be to *add*

```
table table.bar td { background-color: green !important; }
```

Assuming your nesting is at most 2 levels, this works fine, because it overrides the cascading effect described (i.e. the rule applied is no longer dependant on the order the rules are defined).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RQCQS/

Comment: You're right, however he wants the class's styles to be interchangeable between the tables, so he can just replace `foo` and `bar` in the html and the styles will switch respectively.

Comment: The convention here is to write your styles normally as you have done `table.bar td { blah }` and then just duplicate that style `table table.bar td { blah }`. See the html/css in the example.

Comment: apologies I didn't notice the **add** I thought you were suggesting a replacement. You're correct that would work.

Comment: @xzyfer, I anticipated exactly that misunderstanding and italicised my "add", although apparently I should have done more :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want yto effect the direct children of table foo you need some child selectors.
You might need to look thees up as I know they can be used as a work around for older browsers. Additionally I'd advise adding tbody to your table as firefox does this automatically and it messed up my testing of the child selectors:

```
table.foo > tbody > tr > td {
        border-color: black;
        background-color: yellow;
}

table.bar > tbody > tr > td {
        background-color: green;
}
```

Should work in firefox, you would have to test other browsers.
The issue you were having has been explained in other posts but is the nature of cascading style sheets as your code was originally any td inside table.foo was effected by the style table.foo td. Alternatively you will have to switch the order of the styles so the nested styles are always overidding the outer table styles.